# What happened in California in 1994 when hate crime increased so much?

Tags: united-states, crime, california, hate-speech

I'm playing with the dataset provided by [FBI Crime Data Explorer](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/downloads-and-docs). And I found a significant increase in hate crime incidents.

[image: selected states for comparison]

[image: the big picture]

I'm not familiar with U.S. politics and policy. Does anyone have any clue what might have driven the hate crime rate up?

You can download the CSV [dataset](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/downloads-and-docs) here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Summarised from comments*

According to [documents published by the State of California Department of Justice](http://oag.ca.gov/cjsc/publications/hatecrimes/hc1996), California started systematically collecting hate crime data in 1994. This is largely responsible for the spike in 1994.

The decision to collect this data was prompted in part by the LA riots in 1992, the OJ Simpson trial, and other cases in which the race of victims and offenders was significant.